# Which follower to use for Crusader?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

Hello I am new to D3 and I am wondering what the best choices would be as to followers. Should I be changing them constantly depending on the situation? Should I be changing them depending on the difficulty, or the class? What is the best way to determine what follower I should be using. I am currently using the new Crusader class. Help me out here becasue my indecision is through the roof.

Comment: It mostly doesn't matter. Unless you really optimize the follower's items, they don't do much.

Comment: So I could use the Templar for example the entire way and it would be the same as using say the Enchantress because the boost would be minor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend the templar for the resource regeneration.  Crusaders have relatively slow attacks and a lot of trouble gaining wrath regularly.  Having the resource generation helps a lot.

In general I prefer the templar for almost any class for the regen (4k at level 70) and healing (almost equivalent to a potion).

As an added bonus, both you and the templar uses strength as a main stat so its pretty easy to get gear for him.